# Proper use of findAll with startkey and endkey in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I have a pouchdb document database with elements as in the following examples

```
{
 "_id": "course_2_34E82B43-3F14-2FF7-9D37-81B293D2990F",
 "_rev": "18-8f8f2426a12739ffb9f3bebe27d5f158",
 "data": {
  "name": "HACCP formation",
  "isPeriodValidity": true,
  "validityMonths": 2,
  "minNumEmployees": 4,
  "amount": 50,
  "isByCompany": true,
  "activities": [
   "03E0E23F-58C4-3747-A441-6CF8DFE7EF75",
   "CB88B914-281A-6FC2-8A5A-10322AB93B1F"
  ],
  "services": [],
  "offers": [],
  "offerServices": [],
  "unmanagedServices": []
 }
}

{
 "_id": "document_2_24A7DB52-031E-338A-941F-450CC4760E49",
 "_rev": "12-3a704b186d6d1f5490756a983ccdc526",
 "data": {
  "name": "MMC",
  "isPeriodValidity": true,
  "validityMonths": 3,
  "minNumEmployees": 0,
  "amount": 300,
  "resources": [],
  "activities": [
   "B52ED0EB-22F7-800A-B678-D8E36C58354E"
  ],
  "offers": [],
  "offerServices": [],
  "unmanagedServices": []
 }
}

{
 "_id": "resource_2_6CFE5DA9-4756-0933-B11E-1E6C546F1AB4",
 "_rev": "1-0e30424758084f2d1acf042ba8c5fb19",
 "data": {
  "path": "aa",
  "description": "aa"
 }
}
```

I can distinguish among element type by looking at the _id prefix (course, document, resource, ...).
Now I would like to use an optimized query for fetching all elements of say type course.
One option could be by using a mango query like:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$regex": "course_"
    }
  }
}
```

But by documentation [here](https://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html) it seems that a more optimized option is to use the allDocs function in combination with the "startkey" and "endkey". Like for example:

```
database.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    startkey: "course_",
    endKey: "course_\uffff"
})
```

By calling this function I would expect to get only the "course" elements, since they have the "course_" in the _id field. Instead it seems I get basically all the available documents on db.

I'm adding an image from a debug session that I hope can better explain the situation. You can see the *searchTerm* variables passed to database and, the code that performs the call and a part of the results. As you can see only the first 4 results are matching the search key, while the following seems to me random content from the database.

[image: debug session example]

Can you kindly explain me why?

Comment: Do you mean allDocs? I can't see findAll in the documentation.

Comment: Edited. Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I can see no one has answered you. I think the problem is that it is difficult to offer advice without seeing the code or the results you get. For example, allDocs returns a promise but it is not clear how it is handled in the code. If this is still a problem, do you think you could put the code and the results please?

Comment: I realize that, maybe the image I added can be of help. I could share the whole code but really I think it is all summarized in that screenshot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "endkey" property is "endKey". You have to make sure not to capitalize "key". I've made the same mistake many times.